# Can't access hangfire dashboard

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I'm trying to access localhost:5000/hangfire I get redirected to error page(I have a controller which returns relative status pages(400,404 etc.))

This is the error I am getting:[image]

I suppose that /hangfire doesn't exist. The 'HandeErrorCode' it is referring to is from my controller.

```
[Route ("Error/{statusCode}")]
        public IActionResult HandleErrorCode (int statusCode) {
            var statusCodeData = 
HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature> ();

        switch (statusCode) {
            case 404:
                return View("Status404");
            case 401:
                return View("Status401");
            case 400:
                return View("Status400");    
            case 500:
                return View("Status500");
        }

        return View ();
    }
```

Startup.cs

ConfigureServices

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration=>{
              configuration.UsePostgreSqlStorage(connectionString);
          });
```

Configure

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");    
      app.UseHangfireServer();
```

EDIT:
Whole Startup.cs

```
public class Startup {
public Startup (IHostingEnvironment env) {

  Console.WriteLine ("startin app {0}, which uses env {1} and has root {2}", env.ApplicationName, env.EnvironmentName, env.ContentRootPath);
  Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder ()
    .SetBasePath (env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile ("appsettings.json", optional : true, reloadOnChange : true)
    .AddJsonFile ($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional : true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables ()
    .Build ();

  Console.WriteLine ("Current env variables are as follows: ");
  var enumerator = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables ().GetEnumerator ();
  while (enumerator.MoveNext ()) {
    Console.WriteLine ($"{enumerator.Key,5}:{enumerator.Value,100}");
  }

}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {

  services.AddMvc ();
  // Add framework services.
  var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

  Console.WriteLine ("using conn str: {0}", connectionString);
  services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql ()
    .AddDbContext<EntityContext> (
      options => options.UseNpgsql (connectionString)

    );
  services.AddIdentity<User, Role> (config => {
      config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EntityContext> ()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders ();

  services.Configure<IdentityOptions> (options => {
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
  });

  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie (options => options.LoginPath = "/account/login");

  services.AddAuthentication (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie (options => {
      options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
      options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    });

  // SERVICE FILTERS
  services.AddScoped<ActivePackageFilterAttribute, ActivePackageFilterAttribute> ();
  services.AddScoped<ActiveUserFilterAttribute, ActiveUserFilterAttribute> ();
  services.AddSingleton<AccountBilling, AccountBilling> ();

  services.AddMemoryCache ();

  services.AddHangfire (configuration => {
    configuration.UsePostgreSqlStorage (connectionString);
  });

  services.AddMvc (config => {
      config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert (0, new InvariantDecimalModelBinderProvider ());
      //config.Filters.Add(typeof(RedirectActionFilter));
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddJsonOptions (options => {
      options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver ();
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    })
    .AddViewLocalization (LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization ();

  //services.AddScoped<RedirectActionFilter>();
  services.AddAutoMapper ();

  services.AddSingleton<AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider> (Automapper.AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings ());

  //services.AddSingleton(Mapper.Configuration);
  services.AddScoped<IMapper> (sp => new Mapper (sp.GetRequiredService<AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider> (), sp.GetService));

  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache (); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
  services.AddSession ();
  // Add application services.
  services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender> ();
  services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender> ();

  services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository> ();
  services.AddScoped<Context, Context> ();

  services.AddScoped<IAccountBilling, AccountBilling> ();

  services.Configure<AdministratorEmailAddress> (Configuration);
  services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions> (Configuration);
  services.Configure<TBCPaymentOptions> (Configuration);
  services.AddScoped<ViewRender, ViewRender> ();
  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor> ();
  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions> (opts => {
    var supportedCultures = new [] {
    new CultureInfo ("en"),
    new CultureInfo ("ka"),
    new CultureInfo ("ru")
    };

    opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture ("ka");
    // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
    opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    // UI strings that we have localized.
    opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
  });

  // Add converter to DI
  //services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new BasicConverter(new PdfTools()));
  services.AddSingleton<ITemplateService, TemplateService> ();
  services.AddSingleton (typeof (IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter (new PdfTools ()));
  services.AddScoped<MailComposer> ();

}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {

  if (env.IsDevelopment ()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage ();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage ();
  } else {
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute ("/Error/{0}");
  }

  app.UseStaticFiles ();

  app.UseAuthentication ();

  app.UseForwardedHeaders (new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
  });

  var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>> ();
  app.UseRequestLocalization (options.Value);

  app.UseSession ();

  // app.UseHangfireDashboard ("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions {
  //   Authorization = new [] { new HangFireAuthorization () }
  // });

  app.UseHangfireDashboard ();
  app.UseHangfireServer ();
  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IAccountBilling> (a => a.CheckUserPayment (), Cron.Minutely);
  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IAccountBilling> ("CalculateUserCharge", a => a.CalculateUserCharge (DateTime.Today.AddDays (-1)), Cron.Daily (21, 00), TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
  //RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IAccountBilling>("CalculateUserCharge",a=>a.CalculateUserCharge(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)),Cron.Minutely);

  app.UseMvc (routes => {
    routes.MapRoute (
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
}
```

}
    }

HangfireAuthorization.cs

```
public class HangFireAuthorization: IDashboardAuthorizationFilter{

public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
{
    return context.GetHttpContext().User.IsInRole("Administrator");
}
```

}

How do I access hangfire dashboard?

Comment: Debug your code to check what is the value for `statusCode`? Share us the content in your vs output windows. Is there any error message? Comment out this line `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/StatusCode?code={0}");` and use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` to check the detail error message.

Comment: @TaoZhou Before I commented out UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects, I put a breakpoint in controller. The statusCode I am getting is 403. I don't have any specific views for that code, so it goes to IActionResult's view. 

When I commented out what you suggested, it just says that l don't have an authorization to reach the page.

Comment: Share us your current `Startup.cs`. Have you enable any security schema in your project?

Comment: @TaoZhou I wrote custom Authorization filter and it works fine. I'm just curious why did it threw an error when I should have had an access to the dashboard.       app.UseHangfireDashboard (); did not work. However, 
app.UseHangfireDashboard ("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions {
        Authorization = new [] { new HangFireAuthorization () }
      }); worked. 

I will post whole startup.cs

Comment: Is `HangFireAuthorization` your own implemenation with inheriting from `IDashboardAuthorizationFilter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Hangfire Dashboard`, it exposes sensitive information about your background jobs, including method names and serialized arguments as well as gives you an opportunity to manage them by performing different actions – retry, delete, trigger, etc. So it is really important to restrict access to the Dashboard.

To make it secure by default, only local requests are allowed, however you can change this by passing your own implementations of the IDashboardAuthorizationFilter interface, whose Authorize method is used to allow or prohibit a request. The first step is to provide your own implementation.

Reference [Configuring Authorization](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#configuring-authorization)

Update:

For this behavior, this is described above, and is controlled by [HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/a07ad0b9926923db75747d92796c5a9db39c1a87/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs). It registers the [LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/a07ad0b9926923db75747d92796c5a9db39c1a87/src/Hangfire.Core/Dashboard/LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter.cs).

If you want to enable request for non-localhost, you need to provide a `DashboardOptions`.

Comment: If I put app.UseHangfireDashboard(); below UseAuthentication, I get 403 error. If it's before UseAuthentication, I get 401 error.

Comment: @GugaTodua check my update. This is controlled by the hangfire library.

Answer (score 1):

Double check this code with your to see if it correctly config

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add Hangfire services.
    services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
        .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
        .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
            UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
            UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
            DisableGlobalLocks = true
        }));

    // Add the processing server as IHostedService
    services.AddHangfireServer();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobs, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    backgroundJobs.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"));

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Also you dont need to have the url for hangfire like this

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire");
```

just use

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

Because the documentation already said [here](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html)

> When application is started, open the following URL (assuming your app
>   is running on the 5000 port) to access to the Hangfire Dashboard
>   interface. As we can see, our background job was completed
>   successfully.
>
> http://localhost:5000/hangfire

Comment: I am using pgSQL. UseSqlServer would not be suitable so I used UsePostgresqlStorage and got the error saying IGlobalConfiguration doesn't have UsePostgresqlStorage.